# Bluetooth stops working after suspend in 20.04

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, dell, 20.04, xps

After updating to 20.04 from 19.10, I noticed a strange behavior of the Bluetooth manager (using it with a mouse). Every time I suspend the session, by closing the lid or otherwise, Bluetooth connectivity goes off. While it is off, the only option I have after relaunching the session is "Turn off" instead of "Turn on". Also, if I attempt to turn it on in Settings, nothing happens - it just stays off. The button turns blue (on) for a second, then back to gray (off) by itself. The only thing that seems to bring it back to life is powering off the computer entirely; after reboot, it's fresh at work. This is on a several months old Dell XPS 13 7390 DE which had Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled.

Nothing like this happened with 19.10 where things worked perfectly well, although I did have trouble with 18.04 before (in that case it wasn't recognizing my mouse). I have seen a different thread indicating problems may be because of the `python` version, but in my case it is `3.7.4` already. Does anyone know if there's a permanent fix to this?

Comment: Similar situation here on a Huawei Matebook. In my case, sometimes after suspend (not always) BT stops working. It tells me that I have no adapter. Rebooting solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. I solve it with this command:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```