# Integrated Camera and Bluetooth stop working in Ubuntu 20.04 after a while

Tags: usb, bluetooth, 20.04, webcam

I am experiencing some issues with webcam and Bluetooth in Ubuntu. I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E595 with Ubuntu 20.04 from a fresh installation and up to date. Whenever I boot the machine all my integrated peripherals are working fine: I can connect to other devices using Bluetooth and the integrated camera works well. However, after a certain amount of time (more than several hours), these two components mysteriously stop working and are not even detected by the machine. My computer is on a fixed position and I rarely close the lid, so I don't think it has to do with loose cables.

I am wondering if anyone is experiencing the same kind of issues (it seems to be similar to [another question posted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235719/bluetooth-stops-working-after-suspend-in-20-04) , which would explain the time delay); I'd be happy to hear if anyone has a guess on what is happening. At the moment I can't think of any more relevant information, but I'll gladly provide if needed.

Should I report this as a bug? I was waiting to see if it could be narrowed down to a specific aspect of the system (kernel, module, ...).

Below some outputs:

lsusb before:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 5986:2130 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 10d6:1101 Actions Semiconductor Co., Ltd D-Wave 2GB MP4 Player / AK1025 MP3/MP4 Player
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb after:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 10d6:1101 Actions Semiconductor Co., Ltd D-Wave 2GB MP4 Player / AK1025 MP3/MP4 Player
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running dmesg at the startup shows the different devices detected

```
[    1.572633] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=5986, idProduct=2130, bcdDevice=56.09
[    3.570861] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (5986:2130)
[    1.272893] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b023, bcdDevice= 2.10
```

Nothing related to these devices seems to be tracked in /var/log/dmesg after the incident, unfortunately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have done the test with Targus bluetooth dongle and TP-Link AC600 wifi dongle as I had to disable the Intel AC-3165 in the BIOS.

I am using an Apple bluetooth keyboard.

The bluetooth works after the system is suspended both manually via power on/off option or delay (set to 1 hr) in power settings.

I suspect problem in Intel driver resuming after suspend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ; would you mind to clarify what Intel driver specifically? Is your  Intel AC-3165 disabling related to the bluetooth issue, or is it because of something unrelated?

Comment: I purchased a Logitech K380 bluetooth keyboard -  it works better than the Apple keyboard. I also got a Targus bluetooth dongle. The problem is only related to bluetooth only the wifi is fine.

Comment: I purchased a Logitech K380 BT and Targus BT dongle. The problem is only related to bluetooth only. Below  shows the Intel driver being down after sleep.
 date;hciconfig
Wed 12 Aug 2020 15:53:08 ACST
hci1: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
 BD Address: E4:70:B8:63:A5:0F  
 UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 

hci0: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
 BD Address: 5C:F3:70:9B:BE:74  
 UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 

Thu 13 Aug 2020 09:10:06 ACST
hci1: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
 BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
 DOWN 

hci0: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
 BD Address: 5C:F3:70:9B:BE:74 
 UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN

Comment: After browsing a bit more I think it may be related to [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036195/bluetooth-doesnt-work-after-resuming-from-sleep-ubuntu-18-04-lts) and maybe [this one too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179305/19-04-bluetooth-adapter-goes-missing-after-sleep), some people in the first link are having problems with 20.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue (Using manjaro, but same model laptop). This appears to be due to a kernel driver bug on the thinkpad e595. Bluetooth, Webcam, and other devices plugged into the USB stack may have issues or stop working entirely when the system goes on battery power. I could avoid the issue by leaving the laptop plugged in. TLP version 1.4 exposed this bug, and it persists in 1.5.

Workaround: Set `AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on` in `/etc/tlp.conf`

(`AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC` should already be `on` by default)

It needs a reboot to take effect.

TLP Issue report: https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/587

(It says there's a fix in TLP 1.6 beta, but it currently still has this issue from my testing)

**Not needed after applying the above workaround**, but while I was experiencing this issue, [resetting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/681218/137743) the USB bus that the affected device(s) were on got them working again for a while without rebooting. PCI BUS IDs that were affected for me were `0000:05:00.4` (builtin bluetooth and webcam) and `0000:05:00.3` (plugged in USB devices).

Hopefully this helps anyone else who comes across this annoying issue.