# Bluetooth Problem, it goes off permanently and need to reboot for enable in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I am facing a Bluetooth problem in ubuntu 20.04. When I ON my HP Notebook, it works properly but after some time of disconnecting or not trying to connect, it goes off permanently and needs to reboot the computer. Then it works properly but if I want to connect any Bluetooth device after some time, it doesn't ON. The laptop is Dual boot: Primary OS: Windows 10 and secondary: Ubuntu 20.04.
I have tried the following methods:

```
$ sudo service bluetooth restart
$ rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Is there any method to fix it or it is the problem in this ubuntu version?

Comment: I don't have this problem on any laptop I have.

Comment: Did you install any power management tools?

Comment: No, I haven't installed any power management tools.

Comment: On your terminal write `sudo btmon`, then use it as you are using now, and then post the output here.

Comment: Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53
= Note: Linux version 5.11.0-40-generic (x86_64)                       0.955578
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                               0.955580
= New Index: D8:12:65:89:4D:0E (Primary,USB,hci0)               [hci0] 0.955580
= Open Index: D8:12:65:89:4D:0E                                 [hci0] 0.955581
= Index Info: D8:12:65:8.. (Realtek Semiconductor Corporation)  [hci0] 0.955581
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.19             {0x0001} 0.955581
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                  {0x0002} 0.955670

Comment: Related post with possible answers here:
https://askubuntu.com/q/1250594/323082

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem on a HP desktop. Tried all kinds of bluez, blueman stack exchange wisdom, but the thing that always works is to power cycle (sometimes restart works). Same on Ubuntu 20 and 22.